# Создание виртуальной среды на питоне в командной строке, ошибка

Tags: python, venv

клонировал репозиторий с гитхаба через командную строку '''git clone [https://github.com/username/project_name.git'''](https://github.com/username/project_name.git%27%27%27)
установился в папку C:\Users\admin\project_name
пытаюсь создать виртуальную среду командой '''python3 -m venv instalation_directory\project_name'''
выдает ошибку

C:\Users\admin>python3 -m venv instalation_directory\project_name

Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

Comment: Ну у вас питон собственно не находит. А он установлен? Возможно, путь к каталогу с питоном нужно в пути прописать

Comment: C:\Users\admin>python --version
Python 3.10.0

пишет что установлен

Comment: А если `python3 --version`?

Comment: C:\Users\admin>python3 --version
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

а вот так не видит

Comment: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts
причем в path все сделано по гайдам